# Windows 7 cannot display Open with dialog

Tags: windows-7

When I right-click on any file and go to `Open With > Choose default program`, or click `Open with...`, or just click `Open` if there is no `Open with...`, a message box pops up saying "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item."

- If I go to properties and click "Change" to change the default file handler, it works fine.
- I can open any of these files in Notepad++ simply by clicking "Open with Notepad++".
- I can't disable my antivirus, but all files do this, even though I can open them otherwise.
- I ran the system file checker, and it said that it was unable to update some files.
- I don't have a system restore point to roll back to.
- I just recently ran Avira SpeedUp tool on my computer, and I don't know if this is what did it or not. I can't remember whether I had this problem before or not.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try would be to reboot on safe mode and see if the behaviour is the same. If so, you might want to repair Windows using a repair CD. If you don't see the same behaviour, I would investigate 3rd party application that would have impact on the contextual menu.

You can look at this post for information on how to get the items in the contextual menu of Windows 7 - http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/

Comment: To add to this answer, I would specifically recommend running `sfc /scannow` in Safe Mode.  It might then be able to update the system files.